Is Trinitarian Christian theism a simple hypothesis?
For theism to be simple, it must follow from some basic property. Christian theism posits an unlimited agent at the core of reality and likewise a perfect being that has no proper parts as per divine simplicity. Christians posit that this is perfect.
Thus, Christian theism posits fundamentally either a maximal agent or perfection itself as the core of reality. You’d think that one could deduce a priori what follows from pure perfection of a maximal agent. But the trinity is obviously not derivable a priori from perfection. If you knew that the fundamental thing was perfection itself, you would obviously not expect it to have three coequal and coeternal persons. Maybe one person, maybe infinite, but definitely not three.

Äh... isn't this a Philosophy SE question or is there a specific christian angle I don't see?

Well, this can be tied into Christian angle via divine simplicity. This is both a philosophical and a Christian theological question.

Ah, I suppose so. Maybe add that detail to the question?

Yep, added that to the question. But I really want to emphasize, that this question is not only (and not even mainly) about divine simplicity.

"For theism to be simple, it must follow from some basic property" Says who?

This is an excellent question. Unfortunately, I don't have an excellent answer. Instead, I'll attempt to demonstrate why that's OK:
Two of your claims put you on shaky ground in Christian theology, and I think these are the source of your conundrum.
First:

You’d think that one could deduce a priori what follows from pure perfection of a maximal agent.

I wouldn't think that.
I am so far from pure perfection and being a maximal agent that I can't even begin to conceive what a being with those properties would be like. We Christians often find ourselves at an impasse when we try to figure out things about God by logical deduction. "Oh, the depths of the riches and wisdom and knowledge of God! How unsearchable are his judgments and how inscrutable his ways! For who was known the mind of the Lord, or who has been his counselor?" (Romans 11:33-34).
While Christians are not opposed to using logic, it is always subjected to what has been revealed in Scripture. We recognize the impossibility of searching out the depths of God through the power of reason. I recommend reading all of 1st Corinthians 1-2 on this point, see especially 2:9-12 (emph. added):

As it is written,
'What no eye has seen not ear heard, nor the hear of man imagined, what God has prepared for those who love him'--
These things God has revealed to us through the Spirit. For the Spirit searches everything, even the depths of God. For who knows a person's thoughts except the spirit of that person, which is in him? So also no one comprehends the thoughts of God except the Spirit of God. Now we have received not the spirit of the world, but the Spirit who is from God, that we might understand the things given freely us by God. And we impart this in words not taught by human wisdom but by the Spirit, interpreting spiritual truths to those who are spiritual.

Assuming that we should be able to logic our way through the things of God is not a Christian way of thinking about theology. For us, we start with the revealed truths, and let logic build on that foundation, but not give it such free reign as to break the foundation itself. For example, the doctrine of the Trinity is itself a logical inference from the revealed truths. So is Divine Simplicity.
This limitation of logic should come as no surprise. If you've ever had a conversation with a three-year-old, you'll know that what they find logical often is not actually so. And we adults are much closer in intelligence to a toddler than to God. So we have to keep in mind that it is more than likely that many things which seem clearly true to us are not actually true at all.
Second, and related:

If you knew that the fundamental thing was perfection itself, you would obviously not expect it to have three coequal and coeternal persons.

"Obviously?" I suspect that by this, you mean that you can't see any way to get from A (perfection itself) to B (the Trinity). I can't either. But I know that both A and B are true, on the basis of what God has revealed about himself. Just because I can't see how to prove B from A does not mean that no proof is possible. As a mathematician, I'm quite comfortable with acknowledging that, even if I can see absolutely no way in which one could prove something, it still might be true. One must actualy prove it false in order to conclude that it's false, and you have not demonstrated that perfection =/=> Trinity. All you can say is, "this is surprising." Given how much higher God is than us, it would be more surprising if his fundamental nature held no surprises!

In summary, logically yes Divine Simplicity implies that Christianity is a simple hypothesis. However, this is something we believe on faith without actually making the derivations. Practically speaking, Christian theology works by making inferences from the things revealed to us (for instance, one can start from belief in divine inspiration of Scripture, but there are other different but logically equivalent axioms). So practically speaking, the axiomatization of Christian theology is pretty complex, but that's a limitation of human reason, not of theology proper.
There is a fun way to actually logically sidestep the necessity of deriving the Trinity from the perfection of God by appealing to God's own authority. You summarized this well in the comment: "God is a perfect being. God has revealed to us that God is a Trinity. Words of a perfect being are trustworthy. Therefore, we should trust that God is Trinity."

+1 This is a very clear outline of the core of my question. "I suspect that by this, you mean that you can't see any way to get from A (perfection itself) to B (the Trinity)". Yup! I wonder if someone else knows how to make this step.

@ChessIce I doubt that any human being can. One can sidestep around it like this: Divine perfection implies that God has not made a mistake in what he's revealed to us. What he has revealed implies the Trinity. That's logical cheating as it works on the basis of appeal to authority. However, our axiom was that the authority (God) is perfect (hence, reliable), so it's not exactly illogical either

That's actually really creative. Just to clarify what you mean, you are basically saying something like this: God is a perfect being. God has revealed to us that God is a Trinity. Words of a perfect being are trustworthy. Therefore, we should trust that God is Trinity. Is that right?

@ChessIce Yep, that's right. Though there's obviously a lot of logic (covered thoroughly elsewhere) involved in the two claims that the Bible is divinely authoritative and that the Trinity is Biblical.

One theologian to take a stab at this is Aquinas in Summa Theologiae.  He attempts to explain how the Trinity is the result of the fundamental elements of a relationship.  A relationship must at least have two endpoints: a subject and an object.  In addition, the relationship is a third thing connecting the two endpoints.  Consequently, the object, in a sense, proceeds from the subject, while the relationship proceeds from both since it is a function of both.  From this you get the Nicene formulation of the Trinity.
Furthermore, there can't be a subject/subject or object/object relationship, because then the two endpoints are indistinguishable, and thus the same person, and consequently the third element, the relationship itself, collapses into nothing.
Supposedly, this line of thought is also within the Kabbalah tradition, so Trinitarianism is not just the purview of Christians.  Additionally, one could probably derive something similar from Platonic and Aristotelian thought regarding the prime mover, since the prime mover is active, and action implies this subject/object relationship.

This question is something of a non sequitur, as classical Christianity does not understand God in the manner of analytical philosophy (and, thus, the doctrine of the Trinity, which developed in late Antiquity, is incomprehensible in that framework). Christianity does not claim that God is a being. God is the ground of being and Being itself, the unconditioned infinite in which all finite beings "live and move and have their being." God is not a predicatable agent, but that by which all agents can be predicated. It is only in this milieu, under intense reflection on the Christian narrative of salvation, that the doctrine of the Trinity developed, which is an immensely interesting tale in its own right. A good, accessible introduction to classical theism is David B. Hart's The Experience of God: Being, Consciousness, Bliss. As for the Trinity, he tersely describes the process of thought that lead to it here.

Is "X is not a predicatable agent" a predicate?
